# Ruby Type question

Tags: ruby

I am reading data from an XML file then converting the data from Strings to integers, but when I try to process the data, Ruby is claiming the objects are of type String. Which doesn't make sense to me because I convert all of the elements to type integer.

```
#converts the string data array to an integer array
def self.barify_data(data)
    data.each{ |i| i.to_i() }
end

data = BarChart.barify_data(data)
data.each {|d| puts d.class }
```

This outputs:

```
String
String
String
String
String
String
String
String
String
String
String
String
String
```

Can anyone tell me why the conversion isnt happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The #each method runs the block for every element, but returns the original element.

You're probably looking for #map

Comment: thank you, i knew it was something simple.; but I couldnt figure it out.

Comment: More specifically, the `Enumerable#map!` method.

Comment: OP's returning the modified array and reassigning it to data. #map will be just fine in this situation.